# Android system loop7 process

Tags: android, loops, process

I saw android system has loop7 process which keeps running in background. And there are other loop processes I saw when I run some game apps. for example, loop23.

I want to know what these processes doing? who invoke them? I google it, but no answer found.

Thanks,

Comment: Please consider editing your question, adding several hundred words (and possibly some links to screenshots) explaining what it is that you are talking about. For example, you say that you "saw android system has loop7 process" -- *where* did you see this?

Comment: Probably better off on http://android.stackexchange.com/